# This relative module was not found: * ../services/Repository, Vue error

Tags: vue.js

**[SOLVED]** `services/` folder was at the same level than `src/` , putting it inside `src`, following Vue.js [Style guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/), solved the error. Thanks guys.

When I run `npm run serve` I get that error, reading over (a lot) SO similar questions and trying everything didn't work, I don´t even know where that line  `../services/Repository` comes from (I changed the import path in BrandList.vue and nothing changes).
Here is my **Repository.js**

```
import http from "../http-common";

class Repository {
  getAll() {
    return http.get("/index");
  }
}

export default new Repository();
```

This is where I import it, **components/BrandList.vue**

```
<script>
import Repository from "../services/Repository";

export default {
  name: "brands",
  data() {
    return {
      brands: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    retrieveTutorials() {
      Repository.getAll()
        .then(response => {
          this.brands = response.data;
          console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.retrieveTutorials();
  }
};
</script>
```

Project tree
[image]

Comment: You need ad additional `../`, try: `import Repository from "../../services/Repository"`

Answer (score 1):

It should be `../../services/Repository` as it's two steps up in the file tree.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot you can immediately notice that the `services` directory is on the same level as the `src`. A simple fix would be moving the `services` directory into the `src` directory.

If you do not want to do that, you can change the import path from `"../services/Repository"` to `"../../services/Repository"`.

Furthermore, if your project was created with the Vue CLI then the `@` import only works for files and directories in `src/`. You could update that if you wanted to.